# Understanding LUA urlGet and RegEx

Tags: regex, get, lua

Working on a project and have little experience with urlGet and have not found a great reference with examples for me to work through this on my own so hoping that the community here can assist me.

I am attempting to extract some data from a web page, specifically:

https://rrtp.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed?type=instanthourly

On this page is real time pricing data for electricty for those of us on a program called Residential Real Time Pricing. I am looking to pull the numerical cost data from this page to use with a home automation system.

I'm using another similar driver as a base example for my work but its not a straight translation as the example us pulling the data through the Yahoo weather API. However the general principal should be the same from what I understand.  Here is the relevant snippit from the example code, specifically looking at the RequestData Function and the ParseData sections:

```
function Init()
    -- Create Variables
    for k, v in pairs(weatherData) do
        if (not Variables[k]) then
            C4:AddVariable(k, v, "NUMBER", true, false)
        end
    end
end

function RequestData()
    local query = "select%20wind%2C%20atmosphere%2C%20item.title%2C%20item.condition.code%2C%20item.condition.temp%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D" .. Properties[WOEID] .. "%20and%20u%3D%22" .. Properties[UNIT] .. "%22"
    C4:urlGet(string.format("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%s", query))
end

function ReceivedAsync(ticketId, strData, responseCode, tHeaders)
    dbg(string.format("ReceivedAsync[%s]: %s", ticketId, strData))

    for k, v in pairs(weatherData) do
        local tempVal = ParseData(strData, k)

        -- Set property, table, and variable
        Properties[displayProperties[k]] = tempVal
        weatherData[k] = tempVal
        C4:SetVariable(k, tostring(tempVal))

        OnPropertyChanged(displayProperties[k])

        if (tempVal ~= weatherData[k]) then
            if (k == RISING) then
                tempVal = weatherRising[tonumber(tempVal)] or "N/A"
            end
        end

        C4:UpdateProperty(displayProperties[k], tostring(tempVal))
    end

    if(weatherData["code"] ~= "N/A" and weatherData["code"] ~= nil) then
        weatherData["condition"] = weatherConditions[tonumber(weatherData["code"])]
        C4:UpdateProperty(CONDITION, weatherData["condition"])
    end

    for k, v in pairs(weatherData) do
        dbg(displayProperties[k] .. ":" .. v)
    end
end

function ParseData(strData, item)
    return string.match(strData, string.format("%s=\"(.-)\"", item)) or 
    string.match(strData, string.format("<%s>Conditions for (.+)</%s>", item, item)) or
    "N/A"
end
```

SO...

My first question, which I think I know the answer to, is when you utilize urlGet how does it see the webpage?  That is does it see it as raw HTML or without all the HTML markup.

I ask this because I believe it changes the regular expression I need to build to pull the numerical data.

Here are the urlGet and string.match I'm proposing.  I'd appreciate any insight if I'm heading the right direction or not as well as any other input.

```
function RequestData()
    C4:urlGet(string.format("https://rrtp.comed.com/rrtp/ServletFeed type=instanthourly))
end
```

.

```
function ParseData(strData, item)
    return string.match(strData, string.format("\b([0-9]\.[0-9])\b")) or
    "N/A"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern to extract prices: `"(%d+%.%d+)"`. Note that the escape in Lua patterns is `%`.